# Trigger click event on markers and marker clusters with Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Everything works fine with InfoWindow on markers and marker clusters, except **all markers and marker clusters** can't trigger when page load.

[image]

This is my code so far. (See my **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ytliuSVN/7Lg1q5fL/)**)

How do I trigger a click event on all markers and marker clusters **by default**? 
I added `google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click')` but it didn't work.

What do I need to change in the `initialize function` to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/7Lg1q5fL/7/

The problem is that there is only one `infoWindow` variable. Whenever you click the marker, it overwrite the previous infoWindow. So there can only be 1 infoWindow at a time.

Therefore, you gotta create multiple `infoWindow` variable, and set them immediately after you init the markers, not after click.

```
  for (i = 0; i < clusterMarkers.length; i++) {
    var marker = clusterMarkers[i];

    var newInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    newInfoWindow.setContent("<a target=\'_blank\' href=\'" + marker.getTitle() + "\'>" + marker.getTitle() + "</a><br />" + marker.content + "kWh");
    newInfoWindow.open(gm_map, marker);
    infoWindowArray.push(newInfoWindow);

    // ...........
  }
```

(Your code is a bit messy so I only edit the necessary part to give you the idea. Hope this is enough for you to build on top of.)